# Keeping anchor tags and removing other hyperlinks

Tags: php, anchor

Page has hyperlinks linked to other pages as well as anchor tags to jump to a location within the page. I would like to keep the anchor tags and remove all other hyperlinks.

**Anchor tags example:**

```
<a class="footnote" href="#fnx" id="fnx_ref">x</a>
```

jumps to

```
<a class="footnote" href="#fnx_ref">x</a>
```

where `x` is `1,2,3,4 ... n`.

All other hyperlinks (with or without class attribute) within the page needs to be removed. How can this be done? Should I be using *php regex*?

Comment: it would be easier to use `DOMDocument` & `DOMXPath` than a regex

Comment: tried to open the solution a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `RegEx` to find suitable tags within the html it is considerably easier to use `DOMDocument` & `DOMXPath` as below.

The final line simply echos the final, edited html into a textarea but you can save it to a file easily enough.

```
/* XPath expression to find all anchors that do not contain "#" */
$query='//a[ not ( contains( @href, "#" ) ) ]';

/* Some url */
$url='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737604/keeping-anchor-tags-and-removing-other-hyperlinks-php-regex';

/* get the data */
$html=file_get_contents( $url );

/* construct DOMDocument & DOMXPath objects */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

/* Run the query */
$col=$xp->query( $query );

/* Process all found nodes */
if( !empty( $col ) ){
    /*
        As you are removing nodes from the DOM you should 
        iterate backwards through the collection.
    */
    for ( $i = $col->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
      $a = $col->item( $i );
      $a->parentNode->removeChild( $a );
    }

    /* do something with processed html */
    echo "<textarea cols=150 rows=100>",$dom->saveHTML(),"</textarea>";
}
```